# How to run a simple but long python line. From bat?, py script? or what

Tags: python, command-line

That's a single line:
`python -m aeneas_execute_task D:\My Documents\My Videos\videoplayback.mp3 D:\My Documents\My Videos\videoplayback.txt "task_language=eng|os_task_file_format=json|is_text_type=plain" D:\My Documents\My Videos\map.json`

`aeneas_execute_task` is a python script, `aeneas_execute_task.py` located in `python27\scripts`

I tried from both bat and py script and get invalid syntax
This is the site where I got it from: https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas

Under Usage, number 2
I'm not a developer, so if anybody see something obvious please let me know

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the path names in quotes or they will be split into different parameters:

```
python -m aeneas_execute_task "D:\My Documents\My Video\videoplayback.mp3" "D:\My Documents\My Videos\videoplayback.txt" "task_language=eng|os_task_file_format=json|is_text_type=plain" "D:\My Documents\My Videos\map.json"
```

Comment: Tim Pietzcker Thanks for your response, unfortunately didn't work. The aeneas_execute_task part is highlighted in red with the message "invalid syntax". Is that mean that Python doesn't recognize  "aeneas_execute_task" as a script? and therefore doesn't execute whatever is inside it? Or maybe doesn't find the path of the script? If something is wrong with the script I'm out of luck because I'm not going that deep. I just follow what seemed to be simple instructions. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know that module, but according to the site you linked to, the proper syntax would be `python -m aeneas.tools.execute_task [...]`, apparently...

Comment: Tim Pietzcker: Makes sense but lucky me didn't work. Anyway I used their online app so problem solved. I truly appreciate you looking into it.